# Xaxis Labels not matching Data Points - Pandas/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a TimeSeries in Pandas that I want to plot.  I have 336 records in the TimeSeries.  I only want to show the date/time (index of the TimeSeries) on the x-axis once per every 20 or so data points.

Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
stats.plot()
ax.set_xticklabels(stats.index, rotation=45 ) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(NullLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.075))
draw()
```

My x-axis show the correct number of labels (18), but these are the first 18 in the series, they are not correctly corresponding to the datapoints in the plot.

Comment: Is your `plot` call using `date`s as the x values? The easiest way to do this is to pass the actual dates and to then use `plot_date` instead of `plot`. You can still use format stings and locators to tweak things to your liking.

Comment: plot_date() doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps my problem rooted somewhere else.  The reason I am trying to use the above approach is that when I use a DateFormatter for my x-axis, I am getting some crazy values.  My Series type is pandas.core.series.TimeSeries.  When I use `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%B %d %H %Y'))` my original date that was '2013-08-18 00:00:00' is now 'February 01 00 1048'.

Comment: What are the actual values you're passing to `plot` for the x-axis? Matplotlib expects a `float` from a specific start time, and has some [tools to help with conversion](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) to this format - You will want to use `date2num` and pass the output to your `plot` call.

Comment: I am passing TimeStamp/TimeSeries objects to the plot.  I feel like I have done this before and using DateFormatter() worked with no problem and didn't require any more transformation.  But in this example I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `set_xticklabels` which sets the value of the tick labels **independent of the data**.  The ticks are labeled sequentially from the list you pass in.

From this I can't really tell what you are trying to do, but the behavior you are seeing is the 'correct' behavior for the library (it's doing exactly what you told it to, but that isn't what you *want* it to do).

Comment: So how does one make the xtick labels work with relation to / according to the data? I have the same issue of mismatch between xtick labels and the data I pass to the scatter method of an Axes object.